# Windows batch file for invalid microsoft updates

Tags: batch-file, wmic, errorlevel, hotfix, qfe

I am struck while creating a windows batch file which just indicates if an invalid KB article is installed on my computer/ windows server.

This is where i am at now,

Script :

```
@ECHO OFF
WMIC QFE GET HOTFIXID>%~dp0QFE_list.txt
FOR /f "delims=," %%a IN (%~dp0Patch_List.txt) DO (
    CALL :PATCH_LIST %%a
)
GOTO :EOF

:PATCH_LIST
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f "%1">NULL.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ECHO %1: INSTALLED
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
ECHO FIND %1
FIND /C "%1" %~dp0QFE_List.txt>NULL.txt
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO %1: QFE INSTALLED
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %1: **** NOT INSTALLED! ****
)
```

Current output : ---------- C:\USERS\PVENK17\DESKTOP\TEST\QFE_LIST.TXT: 1

Desired output :  : Installed

Inputfile contents : KB3057839,KB3002657

Issue :

Even though it works for 1 KBarticle. When i place more than 1 in the inputfile it is not working.

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Thanks
Prashanth

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 0):

I can make this work by changing the input file format: 1 KB per line

```
KB3057839
KB3002657
```

Then, just remove the "delims" stuff and it works for several items. Not sure of the logic of the last lines. It seems to say "installed/not installed"

And BTW redirect your commands to `NUL` to avoid creating a useless file.

```
@ECHO OFF
WMIC QFE GET HOTFIXID>%~dp0QFE_list.txt
FOR /f %%a IN (%~dp0Patch_List.txt) DO (
    CALL :PATCH_LIST %%a
)
GOTO :EOF

:PATCH_LIST
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f "%1">NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ECHO %1: INSTALLED
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
ECHO FIND %1
FIND /C "%1" %~dp0QFE_List.txt>NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO %1: QFE INSTALLED
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %1: **** NOT INSTALLED! ****
)
```

Comment: I just executed this part of code as directed, but the output was not the desired one.

Comment: OUTPUT  : 

FIND KB3057839
KB3057839: QFE INSTALLED
Press any key to continue . . .
FIND KB3002657
KB3002657: QFE INSTALLED
KB3002657: **** NOT INSTALLED! ****
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0):

After much more debugging i wrote this code, i know its not ideal solution but it works

Code :

```
@ECHO OFF
title IllegalPatchCheck

echo Select a server. (AW/PG)
set /p server=

IF /i "%server%"=="AW" goto AdminWorkstation
IF /i "%server%"=="PG" goto PeripheralGateway

echo Invalid Input.
goto commonexit

:AdminWorkstation

WMIC QFE GET HOTFIXID>%~dp0QFE_list.txt

find /c "KB3057839" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 ECHO KB3057839  NOT Found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 ECHO KB3057839 Found

find /c "KB3058515" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 ECHO KB3057839  NOT Found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 echo KB3058515 Found

find /c "KB3059317" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo KB3059317 NOT found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 echo KB3059317 Found

find /c "KB3063858" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo KB3063858 NOT found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 echo KB3063858 Found

goto commonexit

:PeripheralGateway

WMIC QFE GET HOTFIXID>%~dp0QFE_list.txt

find /c "KB2984972" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo KB2984972 NOT Found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 echo KB2984972 Found

find /c "KB3046049" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo KB3046049 NOT Found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 echo KB3046049 Found

find /c "KB3002657" %~dp0QFE_list.txt>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo KB3002657 NOT Found
if %errorlevel% neq 1 echo KB3002657 Found

goto commonexit

:commonexit
del /q /f %~dp0QFE_list.txt >nul
pause
```

Thanks
Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
title HOTFIXID_KB_FOUND
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /f %%A in (KB_list.txt) do (
wmic qfe get hotfixid |findstr /i "%%A"
if !errorlevel! equ 0 echo %%A: ****INSTALLED****
if !errorlevel! equ 1 echo %%A: NOT INSTALLED
)
pause
```

**KB_list.txt**, in my case, is the list of the harmful updates leading to BSOD. You can, of course, automate and delete, but not always get **wusa.exe** sometimes requires **dism.exe**.

An example of removing using wusa.exe

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:3065987 /quiet /norestart
```

An example of removing using dism.exe

```
DISM /Online /Get-Packages /Format:Table
DISM /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Package_for_KB3045999~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1
```